# Please help me with the following code for byte coversion?

Tags: java

```
 String str = "dBZ";
 byte [] write_data = new byte[10];
 byte[] temp = str.getBytes();
 String s  = new String(temp);
 write_data[0] = Byte.decode(s);


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "dBZ"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Byte.parseByte(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Byte.valueOf(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Byte.decode(Unknown Source)
at qwerty.ByteTest.main(ByteTest.java:9)
```

Comment: What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: I am in creating data For hd5 format, where the data is received as a single dimension array... so write_data is the input

Comment: decode returns Byte not byte[]. what is it exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: @Jeetesh: But how would you expect to be able to decode a whole string into a single byte? It's really not at all clear what you're trying to do. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: just need the "str" in a byte, kindly suggest...

Comment: @JeeteshNataraj You need to explain some more what you want. There are many ways to convert the string "dBZ" to bytes. Either I want it in UTF-8 encoding in which case it would give 3 bytes. Or in UTF-16 and then I'd get 6 bytes. Or I could view it as a base 62 number (0-9a-zA-Z) and then it would represent about almost 18 bits and would require 3 bytes to be stored. Or it could be base 64... I think you get my drift and why we need more information before we can give useful help.

Comment: @JeeteshNataraj Impossibru! The `String` "dBZ" can be a concatenation of three `String`s: `"d"`, `"B"` and `"Z"`; `"dBZ".equals("d" + "B" + "Z")`. It can be an array of characters as well. Each `String` is encoded in UTF-16 in Java so each character in a String is considered unsigned 16-bit.

Comment: Byte.decode(str) is meant to decode a "value" represented in a String into a Byte. For example Byte val = Byte.decode("10") will give val a value of 10 in the type of Byte. Integer val2 = Integer.decode("10") will give val2 a value of 10 in the type of Integer.

Answer (score 1):

Do this....you will get byte from String...

```
 String str = "dBZ";
         byte [] write_data = new byte[10];
         byte[] temp = str.getBytes();

         for(byte b:temp)
             System.out.println(b);
```

Here `b` is a byte..

Also, the documentation for your method `Byte.decode(str)` says

/* Decodes a `String` into a `Byte`.
     **Accepts decimal, hexadecimal, and octal numbers***
*/

and hence its giving you a `NumberFormatException`

Comment: @Jeetesh; you've essentially asked the decode method to decode dBZ into a number, but dBZ isn't either decimal/ocatal/hex. If you're using eclipse or IntelliJ you should link up the java api docs so that you can jump to the definition more easily (and might have found a point to this explanation). Hope that helps.